# Elusive Vox Populi Badge

Tags: support, badges, voting

When I try to vote a question/answer up right now I get the standard "Daily vote limit reached. Vote again in 9 hours." message.  How is it possible to get the [Vox Populi](https://superuser.com/help/badges/110/vox-populi) badge for casting 40 votes per day if I've reached the daily limit at 36?

I thought maybe the badge was just delayed in processing, but it has been 7 hours since my last vote and I've received other badges in that time frame.

Comment: "To be able to reach 40 votes, you need to have cast at least 10 votes on questions."

Comment: [How to get Vox Populi badge when you can no longer vote after 32 votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/117688/267099)

Comment: Slightly off topic, but since I don't see a way message a specific user in this system I guess I'll ask you here.  Why does it seem that users with high reputations (like yourself) submit answers in comments rather than as an actual answer where I could upvote you?

Comment: You don't need to notify me while we are the only two comment posters.

Comment: I gain no rep from posting answers in [meta](https://meta.superuser.com) ... and I can't close vote as a dupe to a question on [meta.se].

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to do that too.  Not sure what to do with the question at this point.  Can't mark it as answered and can't mark it as a duplicate.  Should I delete it?

Comment: Answer written.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### How is it possible to get the Vox Populi badge for casting 40 votes per day if I've reached the daily limit at 36?

To be able to reach 40 votes, you need to have cast at least 10 votes on questions.

So vote on 10 questions first.

> You only get 40 votes in a day if a sufficiently high ratio of your
>   votes are on questions. If you vote on only answers, you'll run out
>   after 30 votes.
>
> The more questions you vote on, the more votes over 30 you'll get.
>
> Bottom line: The Vox Populi badge requires you to vote on a lot of
>   questions during the day you earn it.

Source [How to get Vox Populi badge when you can no longer vote after 32 votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117687/how-to-get-vox-populi-badge-when-you-can-no-longer-vote-after-32-votes/117688#117688), answer by [Adam Rackis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/155403/adam-rackis)